# Relying on ADL for std::begin() and std::end()?

Tags: c++

When iterating over a standard container, do you think it's a good idea to omit the `std::` prefix and rely on ADL to find the definition? Example:

```
std::vector<int> vec = get_vec();
// range-based for loop would be preferred here, but just for the sake of example
for (auto it = begin(vec), end = end(vec); it != end; ++it) { /*...*/ }
```

Are there any reasons to do or not do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `.begin()` and `.end()` (which, FYI, is what range-based for uses here, not `std::begin` and `std::end`)?

Comment: I don't have anything against it. However, I recall a slide by Herb Setter telling us to prefer the free functions over the member begin/end functions.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Because std::begin() and std::end() work on arrays (as well as standard containers (or other objects you have written specializations for)). Thus you can change the underlying type from a vector without having to modify any other code.

Comment: I'd miss out the std unless I didn't feel the code was clear without it. It just adds to visual clutter and begin and end are sufficiently common that you'd assume they are the std:: versions unles you had any reason to assume otherwise. Not an answer as it's just a personal opinion with nothing muchg to back it up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're going to use ADL to be able to change the container type without changing the loops, then add `using std::begin; using std::end;`. That makes sure it finds the `std` functions for containers from other namespaces that have `begin` and `end` members, but no free functions in their namespace.

```
namespace my {
    template <typename T>
    struct container {
        // ... stuff
        iterator begin();
        iterator end();
    };
    // no begin/end free functions
}


my::container<int> vec = get_vec();
using std::begin;
using std::end;
for (auto it = begin(vec), end = end(vec); it != end; ++it) { /*...*/ }
// defaults to std::begin which defaults to .begin() member function
```

Comment: I think it would even be better to re-open `namespace my`, and add non-member functions `begin()` and `end()` for `container`. This even works for legacy code (because namespaces are open). It is also lets you eliminate the `using` declarations for `std::begin()` and `std::end`, which are a pain to use in header-only code.

Comment: I think it is pretty bad practice to reopen namespaces of legacy or any third-party code. `begin()` and `end()` are function invocations, hence they'll most likely be at function level. The `using` directive can be placed at the same (function) level (see, e.g., the answer by Nawaz), resulting in zero side-effects.

Answer (score 8):

> do you think it's a good idea to omit the std:: prefix and rely on ADL to find the definition?

I think it is good idea. It becomes necessary in templates such as this:

```
template<typename Container>
void do_work(Container const & c)
{ 
  using std::begin;  //enable ADL
  using std::end;    //enable ADL 

  //now let compiler search the correct begin/end in the initialization part
  for(auto it = begin(c), itend = end(c); it != itend ; ++it)
  {
       //do work
  } 
}
```

Here since `Container` can be a type defined by the programmer, say in namespace `xyz`, then how would the above function template work if I write `std::begin` instead of just `begin` (in the initialization part)?