# Apply using statement to the return type of a function without applying to the entire namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm trying to create a function that takes an underlying container, and returns a boost::iterator_range based on a custom iterator that does some processing on the elements.

E.g.

```
// The range class, templated on the underlying iterator type
template<class Iter> using CustomRange = boost::iterator_range<CustomIterator<Iter>>;

using std::begin;
template <class Container>
auto make_custom_range(Container& c) -> CustomRange<decltype(begin(c))> {
    using std::end;
    return make_custom_range_from_iterators(begin(c),end(c));
}
```

The code works (given suitable definitions for CustomIterator and make_custom_range_from_iterators).

My concern is the `using std::begin` declaration, which I think will cause std::begin to be imported into the entire namespace where my function is declared.  I prefer not to use std::begin explicitly in the decltype so that  ADL can work (as in this question: [Relying on ADL for std::begin() and std::end()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242542/relying-on-adl-for-stdbegin-and-stdend)).

I think in C++14, I could just use an auto return type here.  Is there a C++11 solution?  Is there a way to let the return type see the using declaration without exposing it to the entire namespace?

Comment: ADL should make it that the usings are not required

Comment: `using` is bound by scope.

Comment: @Creris It's required if you want C-style arrays to also work

Comment: Throw the deduction facility into a details namespace.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ C-style arrays should use std::being/end too(there is overload for them)

Comment: @Creris Yes, but without those `using`s, no `begin` and `end` functions will be found using ADL for C-style arrays.

Comment: @T.C. That sounds like what I'm looking for.  To clarify, I just wrap all the code above in a DetailsNamespace, and then do `using DetailsNamespace::make_custom_range` in the main namespace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the using declaration in a separate namespace:

```
namespace adl_helper
{
    using std::begin;

    template <typename T>
    auto adl_begin(T&& t) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<T>(t)));  
}

template <class Container>
auto make_custom_range(Container& c)
    -> CustomRange<decltype(adl_helper::adl_begin(c))>
//                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return make_custom_range_from_iterators(begin(c),end(c));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef330ad8d0608377)

Comment: If you are using `adl_begin` in the body, you probably want to define it :)

Comment: @T.C. *(or use the helper only in an unevaluated context)*, you're right, thanks

Comment: `template<class T>using adl_begin=decltype(adl_helper::adl_begin(std::declval<T>()));` surely; then `template<class Container> adl_begin<Container&> make_custom_range(Container& c)`.  Or at least `using adl_helper::adl_begin` to pull it out of the internal namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Throw everything into another namespace and put your `using`s in there. Then bring your new helpers into your top namespace:

```
namespace details {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_begin(C&& c) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<C>(c))) {
        return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
    }

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_end(C&& c) -> decltype(end(std::forward<C>(c))) {
        return end(std::forward<C>(c));
    }
}

using details::adl_begin;
using details::adl_end;

template <typename C>
using adl_begin_t = decltype(adl_begin(std::declval<C>()));

template <typename C>
using adl_end_t = decltype(adl_end(std::declval<C>()));
```

In C++14, you won't need the trailing return types, but will also need to do the same for `cbegin` and `cend`. With that, you don't have to remember to have the `using`s ever again and just use the `adl_*` methods everywhere:

```
template <class Container>
CustomRange<adl_begin_t<Container&>> make_custom_range(Container& c) {
    return make_custom_range_from_iterators(adl_begin(c), adl_end(c));
}
```

Comment: I don't like the `C&` in `adl_begin_t`; if they want the lvalue container, shouldn't they ask for it?  `C&&` maybe (which helps with raw array types if I remember rightly).

Comment: @Yakk This works as-is with raw arrays, but I guess prohibits rvalue containers. So, sure, I can change to `declval<C>()`.